# java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19 at 5

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, javassist, java-9

I have a [project](https://github.com/lapots/java-cloud-sample). It uses `spring boot 2`, `java 9` and maven. It can be build sucessfully using `mvn clean package`.

To run `spring boot` application I used the command

```
java -jar java-cloud-rest-api/target/java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But it failed with error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; n
ested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1716) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:499) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.app.JavaCloudSampleApplication.main(JavaCloudSampleApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1776) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93) ~[java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

I added additional argument to start command

```
java --add-modules java.xml.bind -jar java-cloud-rest-api/target/java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But when I run it, I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationFailedEvent cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerInitializedEvent
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:159) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) [spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.finished(EventPublishingRunListener.java:114) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFinishedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.finished(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.app.JavaCloudSampleApplication.main(JavaCloudSampleApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2017-09-09 18:03:42.242  INFO 9200 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-09-09 18:03:42.242 ERROR 9200 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/H
ibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1716) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:499) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.cloud.boot.app.JavaCloudSampleApplication.main(JavaCloudSampleApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [java-cloud-rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.
jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5
.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1776) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.R
C3]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]

        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19 at 5
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1244) ~[javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar!/:na]
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1175) ~[javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar!/:na]
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:185) ~[javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar!/:na]
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:829) ~[javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar!/:na]
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:154) ~[javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar!/:5.2.10.Final]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you confirm the `java -version` from where you're trying to execute the command.

Comment: @nullpointer `java version "9" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)`

Comment: @nullpointer if I switch to `1.5.6.RELEASE` boot I get `org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
` which is the same but without `invalid constant type`

Comment: Not clear from the question why `--add-modules java.xml.bind` is used. This will ensure that the java.xml.bind module in the JDK is resolved but the CNF seems to the Java Persistence API.

Comment: @AlanBateman oh my bad. With the amount of questions I asked it seems I mixed what and where. Aside `javax.persistence` which I fixed using maven dependencies I also had a problem `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`. I updated stacktrace. thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though this doesn't answer on how to fix this but as stated in [JDK-8161256](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161256) about the Constant pool tags:

> Java 9 uses codes `19` and `20` for the module system.

and the way currently `javassist` creates `ClassFile` is by looking up in the [`ConstantPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4-140) (table until Java8) using the [`readOne`](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/blob/master/src/main/javassist/bytecode/ConstPool.java#L1197) method which certainly lacks something like a `Module` for the latest java version. Your dependency hierarchy for `javassist`:

> - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
>
>   - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
>
>     - org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.10.Final:compile
>
>       - org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile

Looking at the [javassist](/questions/tagged/javassist) side of things:

- There seems to be a similar bug registered on [javassist/issues#147](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/147).
- The [rel_3_22_0_cr2](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/tag/rel_3_22_0_cr2) (last release) from them 
  reads *Compatible with Java 9-ea+164.* Same issue occurs with this version of javassist as well.
- So you can probably wait for javassist to come back over this with a solution.

Comment: oh I see. When looked at my dependency tree I completely missed `javassist`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 19 and 20 are CONSTANT_Module and CONSTANT_Package and you will only find them in a module-info.class. So I assume the issue here is the version of Spring + Javassist don't have support for JDK 9 and version 53.0 class files yet. Juergen Hoeller has several online presentations and blogs where he talks about the upcoming Spring 5.0 having support for JDK 9. Some of the blogs mention a version of Spring Boot that will follow.

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by this problem when using Java version 11. I switched **back to Java 8** and everything was fixed.