# java application not working with java9 and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-oxygen, java-module

I am trying to create a HelloWorld module of Java9 following steps were given below.

1. **File>New>Java Project**
   [image: com.hello project description]
2. Right-click **project(i.e. com.hello)>New>Source Folder>enter source folder name**(.e. **com.hello**)
3. Right click Source Folder(i.e. com.hello)>New>Package>enter name(same as source folder name i.e com.hello)
4. Right click **Source Folder(i.e. com.hello)>New>File>enter file name**(java9 standard file name for module which is module-info.java)

   ```
   module com.hello {
           exports com.hello;
   }
   ```
5. Right Click **Package(i.e com.hello)>New>enter class name**(i.e. HelloWorld)

   ```
   package com.hello;

   public class HelloWorld {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
                   System.out.println("Hello World");
           }

   }
   ```

Right click on **HelloWorld>Run As>Java Application** It throws

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.hello not found

My project directory structure
[image: project directory image]

PS: after trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741683/java-application-not-working-with-java9-and-eclipse/46741738#46741738) my project structure looks like below

[image: solution project structure]

Notice: I have noticed one more thing. Afte saving the changes. eclipse(oxygen) throws

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'com.hello'.
>   Unknown constant pool type 19

Comment: **com.hello** is not a valid project name for eclipse IDE

Comment: Could you share your project directory structure. Seems incorrect to specify the project name as `com.hello` as well.

Comment: @nullpointer. I have edited my question. added the directory structure image.

Comment: @SamDev, already tried to change the name from com.hello to hello but the issue persists.

Comment: @SamDev there's nothing wrong with `com.hello` as a project name.

Comment: Regarding the error during build: do you have the corresponding stacktrace?

Comment: I replayed all these steps with Oxygen.1a and all is fine for me. So, either you are not truly running Oxygen.1a (can happen e.g. if previously you installed the BETA Patch feature - please show us the exact version of plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.core), or there's a tiny difference in your project setup - in which case just zipping up the entire project would let others reproduce / investigate.

Comment: There's a thread in Eclipse forums, mentioning the same builder error. This post has been moved from the newcomers forum to JDT as https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089434/ - so if you have more information on this, please add them to the forum thread, TIA.

Comment: I'm still facing this issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that you are using ***[Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) Release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)*** released on October 11, 2017 to support JPMS and Junit5 you can adapt to the following -

While you are creating a new Java project, you need to make sure your `com.hello` package and `module-info.java` is under the `src` folder of the project. You can move them in your project to follow the complete tree that shall look like:-

```
com.hello[project]
|
|-src
|  |
|  |-- com.hello[package]
|  |   |
|  |   |- HelloWorld.java [your class]
|  | 
|  |--module-info.java
```

***Note***:- In case you are attempting to create a project based on Maven(`pom.xml` visible in your structure), you might want to follow answers to [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation).

Comment: I have followed your proposed solution. the issue still persists.

Comment: I would like to give a little more context of the question. I was following [https://www.journaldev.com/13630/javase9-helloworld-module-ides-part4]. My _eclipse-oxygen_ didn't show the checkbox  **Create module-info.java(9 or higher)**

Comment: @shekharyadav108 Make sure you are using the Oxygen.1a release of Eclipse. Updated link in the answer.

Comment: Here are my eclipse details.                                                             
 Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20170928-1841

Comment: I think [https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1089414&goto=1774411&] is also a similar issue.

Comment: @shekharyadav108 Also note that you have started building a Maven project which is not what the link shared by you suggests. So that is another thing to clear off. Would suggest starting afresh and trying it with minimal dependencies on other frameworks. Then gradually involve them...Anysuch dependencies are not visible in your setup that could cause this. I've tried explaining the error you get in [one of my answers previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132019/java-io-ioexception-invalid-constant-type-19-at-5/46133927#46133927)..Make sure you are not missing some info.

Comment: @shekharyadav108 "Build id: 20170928-1841" is **not** Oxygen.1a, the correct build ID is "20171005-1200", perhaps you should show us the full list of installed plug-ins (from About Eclipse > Installation Details > Plug-ins).

Comment: @shekharyadav108 the checkbox **Create module-info.java** has been removed (as of 2017-06-14) in favor of a new command **Configure > Create module-info.java** (right click on the project). Apparently, the tutorial you followed is outdated.

Comment: Awesome. The key here is the placement of "module-info.java" at the right place in the folder structure. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the @nullpointer answer. I'd like to add few more things. What I can see is, you have created `maven` project. And you have entered package name in the `artifact id` column.

Please change the group id and project name as per your need,

```
group name : com.hello
artifact-id: your_project_name
```

Please go through this link once [Create a maven project in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html)

Comment: it is maven project. Check there is this Small `m` icon on an eclipse project name.

Comment: @nullpointer, previously I have created java project. later changed to maven project. trying back and forth to make it work.

Comment: @shekharyadav108 Ya but in both case the solution should be moving the package to src folder as I already suggested [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741738/1746118), since Maven also follow the same structure.